# Как запретить поворот экрана при сканировании штрих кода?

Tags: java, android

Использую библиотеку ZXing для распознавания кодов.
При сканировании экран переворачивается в горизонтальный.
Как это запретить?
Использую вот так:

```
void gotoBarCode() {
    IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
    integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
    integrator.setPrompt("Scan QR code");
    integrator.setCameraId(0);  
    integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
    integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(true);
    integrator.setOrientationLocked(true);
    integrator.initiateScan();
}
```

Comment: в манифесте для Activity screeOrientation укажите

Comment: Для того Activity, в котором вызывается библиотека указан android:screenOrientation="portrait" но это не помогает. Библиотека похоже открывает свое Activity.

Comment: получилось! добавил в Манифест следующее <activity
            android:name="com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.CaptureActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            tools:replace="screenOrientation" />